# Wrong syntax error in list comprehension with Python

Tags: python

I'm getting `SyntaxError: invalid syntax` on the following list comprehension:

```
colors = [(141, 0, 248, 0.4) if x >= 150 and x < 200
          (0, 244, 248, 0.4) if x >= 200 and x < 400 
          (255, 255, 0, 0.7) if x >= 400 and x < 600 
          (255, 140, 0, 0.8) if x >= 600 else (255, 0, 0, 0.8) for x in myData]
```

I don't understand if it's because of the indentation or because i added `if .. and` statements; i tried to remove those `and` but i still got the error. How can i fix it?

Comment: First, you are missing some `else`. Second, no one has any idea what `WallData.Qty` is. Please use a [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use `else` for each `if` you use

```
colors = [(141, 0, 248, 0.4) if x >= 150 and x < 200 else 
          (0, 244, 248, 0.4) if x >= 200 and x < 400 else
          (255, 255, 0, 0.7) if x >= 400 and x < 600 else
          (255, 140, 0, 0.8) if x >= 600 else (255, 0, 0, 0.8) for x in WallData.Qty]
```

---

A method would be more readable

```
def apply(x):
    if x >= 150 and x < 200 : return 141, 0, 248, 0.4  
    if x >= 200 and x < 400 : return 0, 244, 248, 0.4  
    if x >= 400 and x < 600 : return 255, 255, 0, 0.7 
    if x >= 600 : return 255, 140, 0, 0.8 
    return 255, 0, 0, 0.8

colors = [apply(x) for x in values]
```

Comment: Thank you, i was trying to edit my question but i think i ended up editing your instead, my bad! :)

Answer (score 2):

The reason you get the error is that a list comprehension has the syntax :

```
[<value expression> for <target> in <iterator> if <condition>]
```

or

```
[<value expression> for <target> in <iterator>]
```

You can't build a list comprehension like you have done, with multiple values in the way you need.
The way I would do it would be to have a function that returns the right color tuple for a given x value:

```
def color_for_x(x):
    ...
```

and then write your comprehension like this :

```
color = [color_for_x(x) for x in WallData.Qty]
```